# PHP Member function null

Tags: php, class

At my localhost, it works perfectly but on product server it makes some errors...

I get error:

> 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:
> Uncaught Error: Call to a member
> function verbose() on null in
> /var/www/vhosts/XXX/lib/class/class-users.php:21 Users->__construct()
> #1 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/vhosts/XXX/lib/class/class-users.php on line 21'

and my **class-users.php** looks like

```
class Users {

  private $pdo = null;
  private $stmt = null;
    
  function __construct () {
  // __construct() : connect to the database
  // PARAM : DB_HOST, DB_CHARSET, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD

    try {
      $this->pdo = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME . ";charset=" . DB_CHARSET, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [
          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
          PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
          PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
        ]
      );
      return true;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
      $this->CB->verbose(0, "DB", $ex->getMessage(), "", 1);
    }
  }
  function __destruct () {
  // __destruct() : close connection when done

    if ($this->stmt !== null) {
      $this->stmt = null;
    }
    if ($this->pdo !== null) {
      $this->pdo = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for help guys

Comment: So what defines: `$this->CB` ?

Comment: $this->CB is not a defined attribute in the Users class, that's why it is null. Did you forgot to specify an inheritance or initialize CB before using it?

Comment: I tried https://code-boxx.com/simple-php-admin-panel/ this one - and this guy doesnt define it... How is it possible it works at localhost?

Comment: where is $this->cb from? you need remove that, and also your code pdo thrown an error that's why it execute the exception